# folding indented lines before open a document

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to make an extension for vscode that folds the regions and indentation before the user opens a document.
there are extensions now that doing this **after** opening a document, that makes a small delay before folding the indentation which is unpleasant.

I already read the vscode API, I am almost sure there is no preprocess before opening the document, can I do this by any trick or vscode have any plan to add this to their API?

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87897 (`An event that fires prior to a text document opening`)  closed as not planning to work on the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look like vscode don't have any plan to add this feature:

> It's unfortunately not that simple. Just that fact that an extension
> is listening/intercepting the opening of a document, means that we
> need to roundtrip to the extension host. And that enables any
> extension to delay opening, e.g one that's totally unrelated to this
> request but blocking the extension host atm. While that's undesirable
> too, it's often unnoticed because we don't wait for the extension host
> before opening files (and other "vital" things)
> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87897#issuecomment-570323051